# To find out in which table the record is missing if a query with multiple tables is given as Input dynamically

Tags: sql, vb.net, dynamic, db2

I am trying to create an application in Vb.net; In that the user will give a query with multiple tables as input. If no records are returned, My program has to analyze that query and pinpoint in which table the records are missing for the conditions given in query.

For example:

```
SELECT table1.column1, table2.column2 
FROM table1
   , table2 
WHERE table1.column1 = table2.column3
   and table2.column2 = Y;
```

In Table2 the records may be present and table1 its missing.  This means my program has to inform the user that in table1 the records are not present.

User will give query dynamically, my program has to analyze it.
 **Is it possible to create application with this functionality?**

First I need to separate the query, For tat i need to get the table names present in the given query and associated where clause to each table

Comment: it's is possible. but not as simple as you can think. try some code from yourself.

Comment: are you using ado.net or something else?

Comment: Its a windows application....i am using ODBC driver for database(Db2) connection. OleDb Connection

Comment: I just started coding. I was not getting any clear picture how to code. So only posted question. Can u pls give some idea how to code it.

Comment: Wait... that query is just returning a constant, `Y`.  Is this your expected use case?  If so, it's possible to have the query itself return the results (through cartesian products, full outer joins, or whatever).  If it's a real query... how are you defining 'missing' rows.  I mean, 'tableA' may have rows that match a specific condition, 'tableB' may have rows that match another specific condition... but neither show the same ids; so, _both_ tables have rows... Oh, DBs don't usually (directly) expose this to programs, but you might want to look into the explain plans.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible.  But doing it right, making it robust, is probably going to be a lot of work.

Are there going to be any restrictions on how the user codes the sql query?  If there aren't, you are going to have to be prepared to analyze queries of arbitrary complexity, including (depending on your users) CTEs, subqueries, etc.

But if you really want to try this, first look at the syntax diagram of the FROM clause, [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177634.aspx).  This shows you all the forms a FROM clause can take.

Your program is going to have to be able to determine which "branch" of the syntax diagram is in effect, and, based on that, determine which word in the clause indicates a table name.  It has to do that so it can tell what words in the WHERE clause refer to fields from that table.

To do that, you'll need, first, a tokenizer (to be able to pull words and symbols out of the SQL statement), and then, most likely, a finite-state-machine-based parser.

Like I said, this is going to be a lot of work.

Comment: I have a doubt. With the query given in my question, if in where clause it is given like table2.column2 = Y, i can directly separate it. But if it given like table1.column1 = table2.column1. I have to execute table2 and then table1. How can i do that?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand what you mean by "I have to execute table2 and then table1".  Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: In the Query giving in my question,Where clause has "table1.column1 = table2.column3". If i separate the above query into two, First i have to get the table2.column3 by querying table2 and then only i can query the table1 right?